# Magento Awesome Checkout not loading thankyou messege , just spinning

Tags: magento, checkout

I recently installed Awesome checkout Extension on Magento 1.7 CE version , 
everything went smoothly , but the problem is when we click Place Your Order button after filling in everything and the credit details too ,    the loader icon keeps on spinning and the thankyou message is not loading which should load and say your order has been placed.

Here is the screenshot :

[image]

I tried to contact it developer, but dont know why they are not replying.
I hope someone can help me out with this situation .

Error logs

```
a:5:{i:0;s:209:"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1' at line 4";i:1;s:1539:"#0 /home/kibooos/public_html/includes/src/Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/kibooos/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(63013): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/kibooos/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(52695): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/kibooos/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(53731): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `custome...', Array)
#4 /home/kibooos/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(54567): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `custome...', Array)
#5 /home/kibooos/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(52969): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `custome...', Array)
#6 /home/kibooos/public_html/app/code/community/Belvg/FacebookFree/controllers/CustomerController.php(54): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchRow('SELECT `custome...')
#7 /home/kibooos/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(13583): Belvg_FacebookFree_CustomerController->LoginAction()
#8 /home/kibooos/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(17928): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('login')
#9 /home/kibooos/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(17485): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#10 /home/kibooos/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(20062): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#11 /home/kibooos/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 /home/kibooos/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#13 {main}";s:3:"url";s:162:"/facebookfree/customer/login/?referer=aHR0cHM6Ly9raWJvb29zLmNvbS9jdXN0b21lci9hY2NvdW50L2xvZ2luL3JlZmVyZXIvYUhSMGNITTZMeTlyYVdKdmIyOXpMbU52YlM4X1gxOWZVMGxFUFZVLC8,";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default"
```

;}

Error from firebug :

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required '/home/kibooos/public_html/includes/src/WASP.php' (include_path='/home/kibooos/public_html/includes/src:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in <b>/home/kibooos/public_html/includes/src/AWeberCommunications_EmailMarketing_Model_Observer.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br />
```

Comment: Did you check your php/magento error logs?

Comment: I checked the error logs , but dont see any error related to that extension

Comment: Try using chrome or firebug to check what info that ajax call is returning

Comment: I tried firebug , but dont know what info is relevant ,
This is the page i am referring :
kibooos.com   ,

its checkout page.

Comment: i got it 
here is the error on firebug

<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required '/home/kibooos/public_html/includes/src/WASP.php' (include_path='/home/kibooos/public_html/includes/src:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in <b>/home/kibooos/public_html/includes/src/AWeberCommunications_EmailMarketing_Model_Observer.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br />

Comment: :)  found it , thanks for showing me the right way sir,   i found out that Aweber extension was having conflicts with it ,   


Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing from the error, it seems the extension `AWeberCommunications_EmailMarketing` is calling for a file that doesn't exist.

The first thing you should do is to disable compilation in magento & see if the problem persists. Compilation process should be re-run for every change you do to magento including installing new plugins. Disabling it will make sure this is not the cause of the missing file.

Secondly you should check if the file `WASP.php` exists in the expected location or not. The error message contains the classname & line number for where the file is used. If it doesn't, it's likely that reinstalling that extension would solve the problem.

Next thing is to check for conflicts between the 2 extensions. This could be both in javascript side or php side.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to debug this is to using chrome or firebug. Also make sure your php error_reporting is set to display error

See

- [Firebug Net Panel](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel)
- [Chrome Network Tab](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network#http_headers)